# sql retornar dado php

Tags: php, sql

```
$hoje = date('d');
$data_hoje = "SELECT *  FROM vendas WHERE dataCompra = now()";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $data_hoje);

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
    if($linha['dataCompra'] == $data_hoje){
        $hoje++;
    }
}
```

Estou fazendo uma busca na tabela do mysql para pegar e contar todas as vendas de hoje para posteriormente inserir isso em um grafico, porem não consigo imprimir nada. podem me ajudar?

Comment: Acredito que pode tirar o `if($linha['dataCompra'] == $data_hoje){` porque você já fez o filtro na query. Não sei se esta certa a query.

Comment: Se eu tirar o if, ele não vai fazer a contagem para mostrar isso no google chart...

Comment: e se deixar somente o contador?

Comment: sem sucesso.. da forma que eu fiz, ele retorna no grafico somente a data de hoje dia 26, mas ele não busca no bd quantas vendas foram feitas hoje ..

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o `CURDATE()` ao invés do `NOW()` (*now* pega data + hora):

```
$data_hoje = "SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dataCompra,'%d/%m/%Y') = CURDATE()";
```

Podes usar `DATE_ADD()` pra esse controle; como o campo é uma data, é interessante compará-las formatando:

```
$hoje = DATE_FORMAT(date(),'%d/%m/%Y');
$data_hoje = "SELECT *  FROM vendas WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dataCompra,'%d/%m/%Y') = CURDATE()"";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $data_hoje);

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
    if(DATE_FORMAT($linha['dataCompra'],'%d/%m/%Y') == DATE_FORMAT($data_hoje,'%d/%m/%Y')){
        $hoje = DATE_ADD($hoje, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: como eu faço para mostrar isso? porque a variavel $hoje vai receber essa informação, e depois ela vai ir acrescentando sozinha ++ para posteriormente ir para o grafico do charts..

Answer (score 0):

Você está comparando datetime, quando você usa `campo = now()` você está comparando data e hora.

Tenta dar um `date()` nos campos do seu select assim:

```
"SELECT *  FROM vendas WHERE date(dataCompra) = date(now())"
```